# .NET MAUI / IOS AWS S3 file download issue

Tags: ios, .net, amazon-s3, maui

```
var mainDir = FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory;
var metaFilePath = Path.Combine(mainDir, Settings.MetaFile);
QuestionDb.EraseDb();
File.Delete(metaFilePath);

try
{
    var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(Settings.AccessKey, Settings.SecretKey,
        Amazon.RegionEndpoint.XXXX));
    await fileTransferUtility.DownloadAsync(metaFilePath, Settings.BucketName, Settings.MetaFile);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.ToString(), exception.InnerException);
}

var json = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(metaFilePath);
```

Requirement: To download a fresh copy of a file that already exists in an AWS S3 bucket.

Behaviour: This works well if it is a fresh installation of the app. Otherwise, frequently but not always json returns an old copy of the file. When it happens, repeated attempts does not succeed.

Points so far checked:

- Terminating app on the phone to ensure and caches etc are disposed.
- Deleting old copy of the file although this should not be needed. Testing has proven that the file is actually gets deleted before entering into `try` block.
- Creating a new instance of the TransferUtility every time incase of residual information from the previous attempt or any caching.
- On multiple occasions, the file in the AWS S3 bucket has specifically been checked to confirm it is the new version. Still the issue persisted.
- On one occasion, problem resolved after waiting overnight and the new version of the file downloaded.
- It is confirmed that this happens repeatedly (i.e. not an issue like UI being loaded before the transfer is completed).

Comment: what specific nuget package are you using?

Comment: AWSSDK.S3 and Newtonsoft.Json